# Short and byte data types don't work in loop

Tags: java, loops, types, byte, short

I can't add two short numbers when they are in a loop, but when they outside loop they adds well. Byte type behaves the same. But with integers everything works well. Why does this happening?
Java, version 18.

Here is an example:

```
short a = 5;
short b = 6;
short c = 0;
int i = 0;
while(i < 10) {
  c = a + b;
  i++;
}
```

When I trying to compile this, it's give me error: **incompatible types, possible lossy conversion from int to short.**

This also do not work:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 10) {
  short a = 5;
  short b = 6;
  short c = 0;
  c = a + b;
  i++;
}
```

But if I do this(without loop):

```
short a = 5;
short b = 6;
short c = 0;
c = a + b;
```

it works well.

Comment: Your third example behaves exactly the same for me. Please provide a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

In java, the + operator promotes them to an int.
You can cast an int value to short value.

```
  short a = 5;
  short b = 6;
  short c = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while(i < 10) {
      c = (short) (a + b);
      i++;
  }
```

Comment: Works, but I still wonder, why it happening in loop, but if this outside loop, this behaves different.

Answer (score 1):

The full trace would require four citations to the Java Language Specification, but the short answer is that in your working case, where the variables are never re-assigned ever, the compiler is able to find that `a` and `b` are [*effectively final*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) and is treating them as a constant expression whose value (11) is known to be representable in a variable of size `short`. This appears to be technically in violation of the spec, which would require that only "real" final variables trigger constant-expression treatment, but correct in executed semantics.